# How to update a button background colour based on a slider value WPF

Tags: wpf

```
WPF: 

<Grid>
     <Button Panel.ZIndex="-5" Background="{Binding CardColour}"></Button>
     <Slider x:Name="HomeCardSlider"   Height="30" Width="25" Maximum="2" SmallChange="1" Orientation="Vertical" Value="{Binding CardState}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FFF94F0F">
     </Slider>
 </Grid>
```

Class:

```
public class LiveComm
{  
    public int CardState { get; set; }
    public string CardColour { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to update the colour of a button based on the slider value. If the value is 0 the button colour is Gray, 1 is yellow and 2 is red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a small number of states (0,1,2) it can be done without view model via Triggers. Triggers in Button style track Slider value and change Background according to it.

```
<Button Panel.ZIndex="-5">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=HomeCardSlider}" 
                             Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=HomeCardSlider}" 
                             Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
<Slider x:Name="HomeCardSlider" 
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        Height="30" Width="25" 
        Maximum="2" SmallChange="1" 
        Orientation="Vertical"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FFF94F0F">
</Slider>
```

note that I set `IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"` for Slider, it can get non-integral value otherwise

Comment: I have put back Value="{Binding CardState}" for my object binding will this affect anything i put it back and it works but because you have removed it I am just curious.

Comment: @Decoder94, `Value="{Binding CardState}"` will update CardState property of DataContext, which is a good thing when some other logic depends on CardState. It doesn't affect Button if triggers are bound to Slider value directly.